# Despite of several attempts, unable to open port 25

Tags: centos, email, iptables, firewall, port

This question may have been asked many times here but after several failed attempts, I repeat the history:

How do I open port 25 port on my server running CentOS.

Here is my iptables config:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ftp-data
```

Here is the output of sudo netstat -plntu

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1283/nginx          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1039/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5981/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1297/php-cgi        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1177/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1039/sshd           
tcp        0      0 :::25                       :::*                        LISTEN      5981/master
```

Whenever I try to telnet like this

> telnet 158.549.236.54 25

the connection times out. The IP used here is random.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no firewall outside the server blocking this?

Comment: I don't think so. Is there a way i can check that?

Comment: Where is the server located? How is it connected to the net?

Comment: Its in new york from digital ocean.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with your firewall (you appear to have added a rule at the top which allows all traffic).

You main problem is that port 25 is only listening on 127.0.0.1 and ::1, which are both localhost. You need to configure your SMTP server to listen on the 158.549.236.54 interface (or all interfaces)

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: I edited my postfix configuration but it still doesn't work. I updated my answer with the output of sudo netstat -plntu

Answer (score 0):

Configuration seems fine (firewall allows all traffic and mail server exposed on :25), most likely your ISP is blocking traffic to mail port (for fighting spam purposes).

A workaround is to add a NAT redirect in your server from a random port (say 2525) to port 25 `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2525 -j REDIRECT --to-port 25` and then try telnetting to that port: `telnet ip 2525`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the problem is your firewall rules.  Although the first rule appears to allow everything, this is why the output of `iptables -L` is worse than useless for diagnosing these problems - **it doesn't give interface restrictions**.

I suspect that if you were to paste in the output of `iptables -L -n -v` instead, we'd see that that first rule applied to traffic only on the loopback interface.

Try

`iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

and see if that fixes anything.